# Word Frequency strcmp working infinitely using struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, frequency, words

I want to do a read word by word and compare what word with what I have in my struct array.  If I don't have one, I want to add in the first empty spot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

struct cuvinte{
    char *cuvant;
    int numar;
};

int main()
{
    cuvinte multime[100];
    ifstream f;
    f.open("input.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(f,str))
    {
        char * cuvant = new char[str.size() + 1];
        char * abc = new char[str.size() + 1];
        copy(str.begin(), str.end(), abc);
        cuvant = strtok (abc,"     ,/_");
        while(cuvant!=NULL)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                cout<<cuvant;
                if(strcmp(cuvant,multime[i].cuvant)==0)
                    multime[i].numar++;
                else
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                        if(multime[j].numar==0)
                        {
                            multime[j].cuvant=cuvant;
                            multime[j].numar=1;
                        }
                }
            }
            cuvant = strtok ( NULL , "    ");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Strcmp works infinitely and only takes the first word; I don't know why.

Comment: Perhaps if you used your debugger to execute your code one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables while it executes, you would've easily been able to determine that the array that gets declared in automatic scope is completely uninitialized, and accessing it results in undefined behavior; which is the obvious reason for the resulting crash. Have you yet used your debugger to debug your code, and if not, why not?

Comment: I don't know how to use my debugger or what t hat means but I will do reserch about it now.

Comment: A debugger is a tool that lets you execute your program one line or one statement at a time, and give you the ability to look at all variables and their values, at any time during your program's execution. Using a debugger allows you to observe what your program is actually doing, and why, as it runs. Knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: It's odd that you're using different sets of delimiters for the first word compared with the remaining words.  Both delimiter strings appear to have repeated blanks.  If you actually have a tab in the string, replace it with `\t` so it is visible.  If you don't have a tab in the string, supply just one blank; it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it should only take a handful of lines:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>

using WordFrequency = std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned>;

WordFrequency read_words(std::istream& s) {
    WordFrequency wf;
    for(std::string word; s >> word;)
        ++wf[word];
    return wf;
}

int main() {
    std::fstream f("input.txt");
    auto wf = read_words(f);
}
```

Before using `word` you may like to lower-case it and remove all punctuation, so that your dictionary doesn't contain separate entries for the same word, e.g. `Or`, `or`, `or,`.